# PostgreSQL - Exception when insert value larger than a smallint on a field that was previously smallint

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that used a field with **smallint** value. After insert some data, notice that I needed a more larger number type, and changed it to **integer** but now when insert a value out of range of smallint it will throw an exception, but insert the value as normal.

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR: value "40000" is out of range for type smallint
```

Could be somewhere in the structure of the table the reference of being a smallint once ?

Comment: You may think that you changed the type to an integer, but Postgres would not seem to agree.

Comment: Try `\d tablename` to see what postgres thinks is the type of the column.

Comment: @redneb, capacity         | integer

Comment: @GordonLinoff if I put 40000 the value stored will be 40000. Everything is fine except the exception is throw off.